# ASP.NET MVC - Submit button return null on an embedded object which is a list item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, viewmodel, actionresult

I pass the object below to View (cshtml), every works fine. However, when I get the ViewModel object back to ActionResult controller (after clicking submit button), the embedded OrderItems object is always null. Is it expected behavior of ASP.NET MVC?

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
   public int?  OrdersId                { get; set; }
   public List<OrderItemViewModel> OrderItems   { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We need the controller and view code to help you debug this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. The only way that OrderItems would not be null is if you were posting back a set of data named to match the structure of `OrderItemViewModel`, with the topmost name being `OrderItems`.

If nothing is sent then `null` is going to be there. Essentially, the model binder calls the default constructor on the class, so the expected behavior should be the same as using `new OrderViewModel()` and then assigning OrdersId. In this scenario, `OrderItems` will be null.

Comment: How do I get around this?